# Why do html checkboxes only transmit an 'on' value?

Tags: html, checkbox

I'm just starting to learn internet programming.

After playing around with checkboxes, I found out the hard way, that it is only when the checkbox is checked that it transmits an 'on' value.

Why not also send an 'off' value?

Comment: jQuery handles this so moronically. `$('<input type="checkbox" />').val()` gives you `"on"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it must be for brevity of transmission. Each request to the server is sent 'over the wire' if you've got a page with thousands of checkboxes on it, you will find that the amount of data to tell the server "this box is off" is actually quite sizeable (seeing as how you'd have to send the NAME of each checkbox element - that could add up to megabytes of information - which would slow the entire user experience & internet down).

Whereas in fact you *know* that it is off by virtue of it not being sent - so there's no need to send it.

Comment: i would disagree with this answer. the benefit to developers (imho) would greatly outweigh the cost of sending extra data 'over the wire'. for one thing, it greatly couples your HTML display to the processing page (which I think is the biggest argument). second, I would imagine (this is just a guess) that most pages only use a more reasonable number of checkboxes, say 10 or less, and this amount of data is negligible.

Comment: I also don't agree. There are three states if using `GET` parameters for example. `?checked=on`, `?checked=off` or `?`. A checkbox can either be explicitly on or off or not set at all. I want to set the "default" to be on, but don't know if it's off or not set because of the way form checkboxes are submitted. This is a silly problem that shouldn't have been implemented this way in my opinion.

Comment: I don't agree either, when would you need a page with thousands of checkboxes as you suggest?

Answer (score 20):

It is possible to have many checkboxes with the same element name:

```
<form action="order.php" method="get">

  <p>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="olives"/>Olives</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="mushrooms"/>Mushrooms</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="onions"/>Onions</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="eggplant"/>Eggplant</label>
    etc...
  </p>

  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>

</form>
```

The url will later include only the checked values and will look something like:

```
order.php?toppings=mushrooms&toppings=onions&toppings=eggplant
```

This would have not worked well if an "off" value was sent as well.

Answer (score 2):

The default state is 'unchecked' (or off as you state it), so there's no need to declare that information.

Comment: Just to ad @Damien's answer, the reverse could also be true if it was checked by default.

Answer (score 2):

As typical to boolean values, it's presumed off. It's simple to check for, however, just depends on your language of choice. Used PHP as a demonstration, you could check:

```
$myvar_enabled = (isset($_GET['myvar']) && $_GET['myvar'] == 'on');
```