# Convert checkbox 'on' to Boolean before posting to Django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am building a Django app that has a main dashboard with a bunch of on/off toggles.  My goal would be to allow the user to toggle their settings on or off and have their changes automatically saved to the database.

So I followed [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/) tutorial to leverage Ajax form submissions in my Django app so that the user would not have to reload the page.  The problem that I am having (I think) is that the checkbox values are being POSTed to my Django views as 'on' whereas they should be POSTed as 'True'.

I think that this is the cause of the error, because I see this in my error logs:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /update_usersettings/
Exception Value: dataplan_usersettings.normalize_person_name_proper may not be NULL

...

POST:
id_normalize_person_name_proper = u'on'
id_normalize_company_name_proper = u'on'
```

My existing JavaScript and Django views.py are here: https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/25b6221536291c1ba0d1

***Update***:
I've added the relevant Django template and forms code [here](https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/25b6221536291c1ba0d1#file-dashboard-html).  Not that I am using [widget_tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks) for form rendering.  The form renders like so:

```
<form action="/update_usersettings/" method="POST" id="usersettings_form">
<input checked="checked" class="bootstrap-switch-default" id="id_normalize_person_name_proper" name="bootstrap-switch" type="checkbox" />
<input checked="checked" class="bootstrap-switch-default" id="id_normalize_company_name_proper" name="bootstrap-switch" type="checkbox" />
<input type="submit" value="Post">
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

Thanks to Animesh for a great starting point. Here is the final Ajax code required.  ***Special thanks to [Victor K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1833494/)*** for his help figuring this out!

Here is the final Ajax code:

```
$(function() {


// Submit post on submit
$('#usersettings_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form submitted...")  // sanity check
    save_usersettings();
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    $('#usersettings_form').submit();
});

// AJAX for posting.
function get_post_data() {
    var data = {};

    $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.attr('id');
        data[id.replace('id_', '')] = $this.is(':checked');
    });

    return data;
}

function save_usersettings() {
    console.log("Saving user settings...") // sanity check
    $.ajax({
        url : "update_usersettings/", // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : get_post_data(),
        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
            // $("#talk").prepend("<li><strong>"+json.text+"</strong> - <em> "+json.author+"</em> - <span> "+json.created+
            //     "</span> - <a id='delete-post-"+json.postpk+"'>delete me</a></li>");
            console.log("Successfully saved user settings."); // another sanity check
        },
        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            // $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
            //     " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
```

And here is the final views.py:

```
class UpdateUserSettings(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = UserSettings
    form = UserSettingsForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      if request.method=='POST':
        response_data = {}

        form = UserSettingsForm({})

        us = UserSettings.objects.get(user=1)

        VALUE_MAP = {
            'false': False,
            'true': True
        }

        for name, field  in form.fields.items():
            if isinstance(field, BooleanField):
                if request.POST.get(name):
                    if request.POST[name] in VALUE_MAP.keys():
                        setattr(
                            us,
                            name,
                            VALUE_MAP[request.POST[name]]
                        )

        us.save()

        response_data['result'] = 'Update successful!'

        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
      else:
        return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: If you are using Django's `forms.Form`, please contain that part also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this inside the view.

```
CHECKBOX_MAPPING = {'on':True,
                    'off':False,}
class UpdateUserSettings(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    model = UserSettings

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        normalize_person_name_proper = CHECKBOX_MAPPING.get(request.POST.get('normalize_person_name_proper'))
```

You can do this for all the fields you are supposed to receive in checkboxes from the user.

Also, one thing to note here is that you need not use `request.method=='POST'`check inside the post method of a class based generic view. The method will be called only when the request is POST.What you are looking for is `if request.is_ajax():`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for jumping in and trying to help!  I implemented your suggestion but I am still receiving the same error, "dataplan_usersettings.normalize_person_name_proper may not be NULL"

Comment: Can you please check up what values you get in the POST dict. I guess you are getting an empty value from the frontend in 'normalize_person_name_proper'.

Comment: Here is some add'l output from the JS console:  Exception Type: IntegrityError at /update_usersettings/
Exception Value: dataplan_usersettings.normalize_person_name_proper may not be NULL
Request information:
GET: No GET data

POST:
id_normalize_person_name_proper = u'on'
id_normalize_company_name_proper = u'on'

Comment: So it looks like 'on' is being POSTed...unless I am not understanding your question...

Comment: Seems like the problem is with key of the POST dict you are trying to access. You are looking for `request.POST.get('normalize_person_name_proper')` whereas it should `request.POST.get('id_normalize_person_name_proper')`

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you.  So this variable oversight (on my part) combined with your original comment look like it *should* work....The only problem now is this:   when toggling from unchecked to checked ('off' to 'on') the changes are successfully saved to the database....but for some reason when toggling from checked to unchecked, the change does not save to the database.  I can only imagine that this is because 'off' is not matching up with the CHECKBOX_MAPPING dict...any ideas on how to overcome this final roadblock?

Comment: A little research has shown that checkboxes do not transmit an 'off' value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260918/why-do-html-checkboxes-only-transmit-an-on-value

Comment: Then it will just be: 

`normalize_person_name_proper = CHECKBOX_MAPPING.get(request.POST.get('id_normalize_person_name_proper'),False)`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either...still only able to toggle from off to on

Comment: Could you share your models file which contains UserSettings model?

Comment: Hi - thanks again for your help here. I have updated the Gist with my models.py - https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/25b6221536291c1ba0d1#file-models-py